# Google Spreadsheet: Table From Data

Tags: google-sheets

I have data consisting of **n** key-value pairs in a table, **A**

I'd like to produce another table, **B** of size **(n+1) x (n+1)**, where the first row/column are the keys of the original table, and entry **(i,j)** is some function of the **i**th and **j**th value

Ex:

**A**:

```
K|V
---
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

**B**:

```
    a      b       c
a f(1,1) f(1,2)  f(1,3)
b f(2,1) f(2,2)  f(2,3)
c f(3,1) f(3,2)  f(3,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the function you need. Assuming B2:B4 contains `{1,2,3}` , The following can be done. Each will use different functions and will add or subtract in different ways. The first one is the only one, that'll work in the exact way you asked, but that's just for Matrix multiplication - You could maybe use that as base and do other functions on it as needed.

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(--(B2:B4), --TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))

   =ARRAYFORMULA((--(B2:B4)/--TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))


   =ARRAYFORMULA((--(B2:B4)+--TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))

   =ARRAYFORMULA((--(B2:B4)---TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))
```

Comment: Perfect. Gave me exactly what I wanted (namely, the 2nd one happened to be my **f** :) ) Thanks